# How to assign a reference to a dynamically created object using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

There are some answers to similar questions, but none of them work for me. Most of them are geared towards Forms whereas I am trying to add objects directly onto Excel worksheets. Beyond that, nearly all are incredibly complicated solutions for something that should not be so difficult.

Here is the straightforward kind of thing I'm looking for - but I need it for ToggleButton and ComboBox. The code below works for CommandButton but it seems to have no analog for the other ActiveX object types, so far as I could tell.

```
Sub AddButtons()
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim btn As Button

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Set btn = ws.Buttons.Add(10, 20, 30, 40)
        Debug.Print ws.Name
        ' MySub_[worksheet name] will be executed when btn is clicked
        btn.OnAction = "MySub_" & ws.Name
        btn.Caption = ws.Name
        ' Set additional btn properties as needed
    Next ws
End Sub
```

(I'm not actually trying to create an object for each worksheet, but this example shows how one can loop through some construct and tether customized code to the object created within each iteration.)

Thanks!

Comment: So you are wanting to run `MySub_<...>` when interacting with these toggle buttons and combo boxes as well? Your first paragraph is nothing but fluff and provides no information, the 2nd one looked promising when you said _"Here is the straightforward kind of thing I'm looking for..."_ but then describes how the code below works and didn't describe anything about what you actually needed, and the 3rd is your thoughts, outloud. Can you please describe what you are actually needing to happen? See [ask].

Comment: K. Davis, Let me address your points one by one: "So you are wanting to run MySub_<...> when interacting with these toggle buttons and combo boxes as well?" Not sure what you mean by "as well", because what would be the point of a control that doesn't do anything? "Your first paragraph is nothing but fluff and provides no information" It provides a lot of information to the potential answerer: 1) Don't point me to another SO answer; 2) Advise for a worksheet and not for a form; 3) If it takes you 50 LOC to solve this, it probably isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: "didn't describe anything about what you actually needed" Yes, I absolutely did. The 2nd paragraph states: "but I need it for ToggleButton and ComboBox". "the 3rd is your thoughts, outloud" I'm providing helpful context around the provided code to explain more precisely what I am trying to accomplish. Thank you for the link, but I think the way I posted my question is straightforward, concise, and helpfully documents the effort I put into resolving things myself.

Answer (score 1):

Activex controls are OLEObjects. I have shown how to add checkbox below.

```
Sub AddButtons()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim btn As OLEObject
    Debug.Print ("Start")
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Set btn = ws.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CheckBox.1", Link:=True, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=False, left:=10, top:=10, width:=20, _
        height:=20)
        Debug.Print (ws.Name)
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Gro, thanks for your answer. It clears the hurdle of setting btn to the object, but when I add the line `btn.OnAction = "MySub"`, I get: "Run-time error '1004': Unable to set the OnAction property of the OLEObject class".

Comment: Actually, `btn.OnAction` makes less sense for a CheckBox than a CommandButton, although I'm not sure how to event-handle the CheckBox or even get its value. None of the OLE properties or actions seem to address either of these needs. What am I missing?